# Elections took place, Impersonal Passive

Tags: passive-voice

I am reading one PhD thesis at the moment, and encountered an explanation which states that the form of the verb take used in the following sentence is 'impersonal passive'.

> On 25 April, for the first time in Portugal, fully free and democratic
>   elections took place.

I don't think it is correct, but am not quite sure, because I believe that this is an active sentence. Could you please explain to me whether there is a mistake in this claim or no not?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but *took place* in that sentence is synonymous with *happened* or *occurred* and makes complete sense.

Comment: You're correct. This is not a passive construction. Whoever wrote that explanation didn't understand what "passive" meant. That means that you shouldn't trust their  judgement on "impersonal", or any other grammatical term. Passive is pretty basic; people who don't know what passive is should not be commenting on English grammar.

Answer (score 3):

This is a use of the verb 'to take' in the active voice.  Changing 'took place' to 'were conducted' would introduce a passive verb.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Not all impersonal constructions are passive; the sentence you quote is impersonal, but it uses the active form of the verb (as Sam Burns says).

Geoff Pullum, a linguist, explains in a Language Log post "[The passive in English](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922)" that passive constructions in English always use a *participle* (almost always the *past participle*); but you can see that there is no participle in "took place." This is the simplest test I have encountered yet for seeing if a verb form might be passive. Of course, it doesn't work the other way (not all uses of participles are passive).

Comment: You cannot form a passive out of *to take place* because it operates as a phrasal intransitive verb, so there is no object to switch into subject position: the place was not taken by the elections. Moreover, the participle under discussion here is almost always with the **past** participle (sometimes called the *“‑EN”* form, mutatis mutandis), as that one is by its nature passive, rather than with the gerund-participle (sometimes called the *“‑ING”* form) used for active progressives.

Comment: @sumelic: Passive **always** uses a past participle, and there's always a form of _be_ right before it. If it were a present participle with a form of _be_ in front of it, it would be the Progressive, not the Passive. That's how they stack up in the verb chain: Modal+Inf, _have_ +PastPart, _be_ +PresPart, _be_ +PastPart, MainVb.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I'm just summarizing what Pullum says in the linked post. Of course different linguists often use different terminology; perhaps I should make that more clear. The construction he talks about is forms like "That rash needs looking at by a specialist," which use a present participle in standard language, although a past participle is used instead in some regional varieties.

Comment: Oh, he wants to call that passive? I'm surprised. That's a special collocation with _need_ (and maybe some other equally weird verbs); it's like _The bridge is building_ vs _The bridge is being built_, as we would now say it.