# What's the passive form of "I have been learning English for 5 years"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, tenses, passive-voice

Is it

"English has been being learned for 5 years"

Or

"English has been learned for 5 years"

The first one sounds awkward and the second one implies (to me at least) that the action was done 5 years ago and it was not continuous. And "English is being learned for 5 years" is not exactly the passive form of the OP. That's why I'm a bit confused.

Comment: The passive only makes sense if the patient (English) has been affected by the agent. Passivising this seems fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @StuartF so on that basis the sentence "the lesson will be learned" is also wrong, right?

Comment: Related: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/426951), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/354362), [3](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922), [4](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/passive_loathing.pdf), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/277693).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is just an exercise, your first clause, using the present perfect continuous, is the correct conversion from active to passive and is grammatically correct:

> Active: *I have been learning English for 5 years*
>
> Passive: *English has been being learned [by me] for 5 years*

As you noted, it sounds awkward, which can happen with [the perfect continuous forms in the passive voice](https://www.theenglishspace.com/grammar/passive-voice/passive-voice-and-tense.html).

Nonethelesss, there are plenty of perfectly reasonable-sounding sentences that use the perfect continuous passive:

> *Recently, the work has been being done by John.*
>
> *The restaurant’s fantastic dinners had been being prepared by Chef Jones for two years before he moved to Paris.*
>
> *The mural will have been being painted by the famous artist for over six months by the time it is finished.*
>
> <sub>Source: [Englishpage.com — Active and Passive Verb
> Forms](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html)</sub>

But your clause would need some more or different context to even approach stylistic acceptability:

> *English has been being taught for 5 years — and English has been being learned, but only by me.*

Still, that’s a stretch.

Comment: What a well considered answer. And I nearly **D**Vd on the premise that 'not all passivisations are acceptable, end of story' _was_ the end of the story.

Answer (score -3):

The action was not completed. It has been continuing ..

I have been learning English for 5 years.- present perfect continuous tense

English has been being learned for 5 years by me.

I have learned English. - present perfect tense. The action is completed.

English has been learned by me.

Comment: This is ungrammatical. See [these links](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/574379/whats-the-passive-form-of-i-have-been-learning-english-for-5-years#comment1431499_574379) for why.